# Talend - tSystem error after deployment on the TMC

Tags: powershell, talend

I'm facing an issue with the deployment of a job with a tSystem component.

So first here is the job :

[image]

The job execute a powershell command that extract data from an activedirectory, I tried the powershell command on my local environnement for testing and also tested it on the server (with the remote engine installed) and worked perfectly fine.

here is the configuration of the tSystem component :

[image]

The job works fine in the studio. But fail when I deployed to the TMC, so I tried to execute the job from the .bat file on the remote engine server and also worked, the only fail is when I execute it from the TMC.

[image]

So is there something I missed, or that I can check to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: JAVA Error says you cannot create.  Try running PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  If that does not work see : https://www.makeuseof.com/could-not-create-java-virtual-machine-windows/

Comment: the thing is that the command works, the job can run when I execute the bat file generated by talend (without run as admin), It's only when I execute it from the Talend Management Console

Comment: Bat files automatically inherit the ADMIN rights.  Powershell does not unless you start PS as an Admin.